# I want output as 1 2 3 4 using one semaphore value. How to achieve this?

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I want to print 1 2 3 4 using this code and using only one semaphore can anyone tell me how to this and i have tried one approach that is not printing the desired result.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
sem_t sem;
void *thread1(void *argv)
{
   printf("1\t");
   sem_wait(&sem);
    printf("3\t");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void *thread2(void *argv)
{
//    sem_post(&sem);
   sem_post(&sem);
    printf("2\t");
    sem_wait(&sem);
    printf("4\t");

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(void)
{
    sem_init(&sem,0,0);
    pthread_t p1, p2;
    pthread_create(&p1,NULL,thread1,NULL);
    pthread_create(&p2,NULL,thread2,NULL);
    pthread_join(p1,NULL);
    pthread_join(p2,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where does `thread1` call `sem_post`?

Comment: << i have tried one approach that is not printing the desired result. >>
... and what is the result, then ?

Comment: I doubt that kind of sorting is possible by using just 1 semaphore.

Comment: @t.m. It's possible, if one thinks about the order in which the threads waits and posts.

Answer (score 1):

Without extra state shared between the two threads, it is not possible to guarantee alternate execution. You can achieve the extra state with a global variable.

In the following example, the sem is used to effectively force one thread at a time, and the 'next' control which thread has to actually perform the next task.

To generalize, and improve testing, range extended to 1 thru 9 (instead of 1 to 4). Can be scaled down by tuning the loops.

Once forked, e
ach thread, will check if it is his turn to execute (i==next)

- if it is, it will, WITH THE SEMAPHORE LOCKED: execute his job (print the next int), and set the next to indicate that the next stop should run
- If it is not his turn, it will release the lock, and try again.

Even if one thread takes manage to lock/unlock repeated, at some point of time, the system will allow the alternate thread to lock the semaphore and get his job done.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
sem_t sem;
static volatile int next ;
void *thread1(void *argv)
{
    for (int i=1 ; i<10 ; i+=2 ) {
       // Spinlock like loop
       while ( 1 ) {
           sem_wait(&sem) ;
           if ( i == next ) break ;
           sem_post(&sem) ;
       } ;
       // Semaphore still locked
       printf("%d\n", i) ;
       next++ ;
       sem_post(&sem) ;
   }
}
void *thread2(void *argv)
{
    for (int i=2 ; i<10 ; i+=2 ) {
       // Spinlock like loop
       while ( 1 ) {
           sem_wait(&sem) ;
           if ( i == next ) break ;
           sem_post(&sem) ;
       } ;
       // Semaphore still locked
       printf("%d\n", i) ;
       next++ ;
       sem_post(&sem) ;
    } ;
}
int main(void)
{
    sem_init(&sem,0,0);
    pthread_t p1, p2;
    pthread_create(&p1,NULL,thread1,NULL);
    pthread_create(&p2,NULL,thread2,NULL);
    next = 1 ;
    sem_post(&sem) ;
    pthread_join(p1,NULL);
    pthread_join(p2,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Inspired by Java article on similar topic: https://www.baeldung.com/java-even-odd-numbers-with-2-threads